# Postgres - Index a materialised view with groupby and filter

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I am running Postgres 14 in a k8s cluster.

I have the following table (which has ~15 million rows):

```
                                                     Table "public.messages"
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id         | character varying           |           | not null |         | extended |             |              |
 channel_id | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 author_id  | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 is_deleted | boolean                     |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
Indexes:
    "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_messages_author_id" btree (author_id) CLUSTER
    "ix_messages_channel_id" btree (channel_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "messages_author_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "messages_channel_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES channels(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Access method: heap
```

The id fields need to be character varying, since the dashboarding tool we use (metabase) truncates BIGINTs, as it treats all integers as JS ints, so it makes the drag and drop query builder unusable unless these are stored as strings. Trust me, as soon as I can, these are being changed to BIGINTs.

To avoid having to query this table every time we want to count how many messages a user has, as this is done multiple times in a minute at peak times, I have defined a materialised view `user_has_approx_message_count` as:

```
                                 Materialized view "public.user_has_approx_message_count"
    Column     |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
---------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 author_id     | character varying |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 message_count | bigint            |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
Indexes:
    "user_has_approx_message_count_author_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (author_id)
View definition:
 SELECT messages.author_id,
    count(*) AS message_count
   FROM messages
  WHERE NOT messages.is_deleted AND (messages.channel_id::text <> ALL (ARRAY['267659945086812160'::character varying, '607247579608121354'::character varying]::text[]))
  GROUP BY messages.author_id;
Access method: heap
```

Using `pg_cron` I have this view concurrently refreshing every minute, to get fairly accurate numbers. However, EXPLAIN ANALYSE on this query shows that it takes ~3-4 seconds each time:

```
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=313672.31..316563.54 rows=11412 width=26) (actual time=3074.494..3202.513 rows=141810 loops=1)
   Group Key: author_id
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=313672.31..316335.30 rows=22824 width=26) (actual time=3074.397..3157.556 rows=188369 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=312672.29..312700.82 rows=11412 width=26) (actual time=3025.723..3038.027 rows=62790 loops=3)
               Sort Key: author_id
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2592kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2608kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2576kB
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=311789.10..311903.22 rows=11412 width=26) (actual time=2420.817..2939.233 rows=62790 loops=3)
                     Group Key: author_id
                     Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 4657kB  Disk Usage: 85800kB
                     Worker 0:  Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 4657kB  Disk Usage: 86856kB
                     Worker 1:  Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 4401kB  Disk Usage: 89984kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..281775.38 rows=6002745 width=18) (actual time=11.064..1188.773 rows=4807063 loops=3)
                           Filter: ((NOT is_deleted) AND ((channel_id)::text <> ALL ('{267659945086812160,607247579608121354}'::text[])))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 230310
 Planning Time: 0.463 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 33
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 9.259 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.099 ms, Emission 43.675 ms, Total 56.032 ms
 Execution Time: 3224.036 ms
```

I have tried adding the index `create index message_count_idx on messages (author_id, channel_id, is_deleted);`. However, running explain analyse again, shows that postgres doesn't use this index, even if I disable seq scans.

So my question (after all of that context) is there an index I can add here that could speed up this query?

Comment: I think you got the column order wrong: try `channel_id, is_deleted, author_id`.

Comment: @mustaccio I tried adding the index, then running with and without seq scans enabled. It doesn't seem to have that much impact, unless I've done it wrong? See this paste for the full output: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/odirivurux.sql?noredirect

Comment: The condition on `is_deleted` and `channel_id` is filtering out few rows (230k) compared to the rows it keeps (4,8M). An index would be useful in the opposite case. To see a drastic improvement in this, I'd try to recompute only the counters of the users that had a change in their messages since the last run.

Comment: In my hands v14 it does use that index (not that it gets a great deal of benefit from it).  It actually uses it in preference to the seq scan, and certainly uses it if seq scans are disabled.

Comment: Your work_mem is too low for this type of query.  Increasing it should give you better performance no matter which of those plans it chooses.  (But not 50x better if that is what you are hoping for).

Comment: Storing `bigint` values as `varchar` is so many worlds of bad. Among other things it contributes to your `work_mem` shortage. 18 digits stored as `varchar` occupy 19 bytes on disk instead of just 8 bytes as `bigint`. I don't know metabase, but are you sure it cannot handle `bigint`? If so, I would first try to ditch that software, and next create a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) to butcher the data types on top of a properly designed table ...

Comment: Your question seems to be about improving the performance of your minutely refresh that takes ~3 seconds, that doesn't seem like a problem. Surely, you care more about the query against this materialized view - the one that is being executed by your front end? A brief google suggests that PostgreSQL doesn't automatically rewrite the query for you, so you'll need to do that yourself to reference the materialized view.

Comment: With the right index and a sufficiently vacuumed table, querying the main table to count messages for a single given author_id "multiple times in a minute" should be completely trivial.  Certainly less work preemptively recomputing all 140,000 of them once a minute (assuming that task you were describing actually was for a single author_id at a time)